# different results for the same code with tf.control_dependencies

Tags: tensorflow, variables, session

I run a piece of code twice and get two different results

The code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[], name='x')
y = tf.Variable(2, dtype=tf.int32)
assign_op = tf.assign(y, y + 1)
out = x * y
with tf.control_dependencies([assign_op]):
    out_ = out+2
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(3):
        print('output:', sess.run(out_, feed_dict={x: 1}))
```

First output:

```
output: 4
output: 5
output: 6
```

Second output:

```
output: 4
output: 6
output: 6
```

Can someone please explain why does it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow does not record the order in which operations are created as in a normal python program but only keeps track of their dependencies thus only guaranteeing that all dependencies of an `operation/op` are executed before the `op`executes.

So in some instances, `out_` may be updated either after updating the value of `y` and in other cases it executes before updating the  `y` since `out_` only has a transitive dependency to `y`.i.e. it depends on `y` through the `out` variable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is some indeterminism in the order that operations are executed. `out_` will always be equal to `out + 2`, and the `control_dependencies` block there is not making any difference in this case. The question is what is the value of `out`. In some cases, `out` will be computed before `y` is updated, in other cases after that, so you can get `4, 5, 6`, `5, 6, 7` and all in between.

If you want to ensure that `out` is computed *after* `y` has been updated, you can do:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[], name='x')
y = tf.Variable(2, dtype=tf.int32)
y_new = tf.assign(y, y + 1)  # tf.assign always returns the updated value
out = x * y_new
out_ = out + 2
```

This will always print the sequence `5, 6, 7`.

If you want to make sure that `out` is computed *before* `y` has been updated, you can do:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[], name='x')
y = tf.Variable(2, dtype=tf.int32)
out = x * y
with tf.control_dependencies([out]):
    y_new = tf.assign(y, y + 1)
out_ = out + 2
```

However, in this case evaluating `out_` will not update `y` (because `out_` does not depend on the update). If you still want to have that effect (otherwise you would always get `4` in the output), you can do:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[], name='x')
y = tf.Variable(2, dtype=tf.int32)
out = x * y
with tf.control_dependencies([out]):
    y_new = tf.assign(y, y + 1)
# Force update y every time out is evaluated
with tf.control_dependencies([y_new]):
    out = tf.identity(out)
out_ = out + 2
```

Which will always show the sequence `4, 5, 6`.